# Removing escaping characters from String in QT

Tags: json, qt

I get a json string drom my network reply it looks like

```
{\"topic\":\"ddd\",\"payload\":\"{\\\"eeee\\\":\\\"eee\\\",\\\"thingUID\\\":\\\"eee\\\",\\\"ee\\\":\\\"eee\\\",\\\"serialNumber\\\":\\\"eee\\\",\\\"epoch\\\":\\\"eeee\\\",\\\"eee\\\":\\\"eee\\\",\\\"eee\\\":\\\"eee\\\"}\",\"type\":\"eee\"}\n\n
```

how can i remove the best and fastest way all these backslahes "" in QT???

I do it like this

```
QByteArray     data = _sseReply->readAll();
data = data.replace("\\\"", "\"");
        data = data.replace("}\"", "}");
        data = data.replace("\"{", "{");
```

any cooler solution available??

Answer (score 0):

Just use `QJsonDocument::fromJson(data).object()` and don't need remove backslashes.